# Date time range of shift in a day split into intervals of 10 minutes C#

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, group-by, intervals

I am wondering if anyone can help me, I have a collection of start times and end times for a work shift of a day. the hours can be spread across the day. I am trying group by the hour in day (like 0, 1, 2...23, 24) and show that hour in intervals of 10 minutes or worked or not worked. So, I would like to get the end result like below:

I want to able distinguish between worked and not on a hourly basis, the input provides the worked but I have calculate the not worked, I created a method for handling if a time falls outside a 10 minute interval it will set to the nearest one. Method called DoRounding:

Example:

```
9 am => 0 - 10 Worked 
       10 - 20 Not Worked
       20 - 30 Worked
       30 - 40 Worked
       40 - 50 Worked
       50 - 60 Worked
```

The time that fails out of the period can be be handled like so

```
private static int DoRounding(DateTime date)
{

    if (Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Contains(date.Minute))
        return 0;

    if (Enumerable.Range(10, 20).Contains(date.Minute))
        return 20;

    if (Enumerable.Range(20, 30).Contains(date.Minute))
        return 30;

    if (Enumerable.Range(30, 40).Contains(date.Minute))
        return 40;

    if (Enumerable.Range(40, 50).Contains(date.Minute))
        return 50;

    return 60;
}
```

My method to explode the workblock (I was trying to break down the work period into hours here so I could add the missing parts in another method)

```
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, DateTime>> CalculateIntervals(WorkPeriod workBlock)
    {
        yield return new Tuple<int, DateTime>(workBlock.StartTime.Hour, workBlock.StartTime);

        var dateTime = new DateTime(workBlock.StartTime.Year, workBlock.StartTime.Month, workBlock.StartTime.Day, workBlock.StartTime.Hour, workBlock.StartTime.Minute, 0, workBlock.StartTime.Kind).AddHours(1);

        while (dateTime < workBlock.EndTime)
        {
            yield return new Tuple<int, DateTime>(dateTime.Hour, dateTime);
            dateTime = dateTime.AddHours(1);
        }

        yield return new Tuple<int, DateTime>(workBlock.EndTime.Hour, workBlock.EndTime);
    }
```

My attempt at grouping (I want to group into the time slots here to the hour and the intervals such as 1 pm, 0 - 10 minutes and mark it as worked but if an interval was missing from here add it as not worked)

```
    public static void WorkingHourIntervalStrings(List<WorkPeriod> WorkingHours)
    {
        var output = new List<Tuple<int, DateTime>>();

        foreach (var result in WorkingHours.Select(CalculateIntervals))
            output.AddRange(result);

        output = output.OrderBy(x => x.Item2).ToList();

        var test = output.GroupBy(
            p => p.Item1,
            p => p.Item2.Minute,
            (key, g) => new { Worked = key, Minute = g.ToList() });
    }
```

Class

```
public class WorkPeriod 
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Calling

```
 var input = new List<WorkPeriod>
 {
   new WorkPeriod { StartTime  = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 9, 40, 56), EndTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 14, 22, 12) },
   new WorkPeriod { StartTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 9, 50, 56), EndTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 14, 59, 12) },
   new WorkPeriod { StartTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 13, 40, 56), EndTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 18, 22, 12) },
   new WorkPeriod { StartTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 19, 40, 56), EndTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 23, 22, 12) }
};

  TimeIntervals.WorkingHourIntervalStrings(input);
```

Possible output structure:

```
public class Interval
{
    public Interval() => Contents = new List<Contents>();

    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public List<Contents> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Contents
{
    public bool Worked { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the tuple in the output expected to represent? Given that any ten minute interval can be "partly worked, partly not work", how would you expect that to be represented? (I also suspect your `DayWorked` class isn't ideally named, because it's only a *portion* of a day worked - it looks like the *actual* day would consist of multiple instances...)

Comment: I have updated that class name to avoid confusion thanks for that, the tuple was meant to have the hour and the interval. I see that this was not a good choice, I was having two issues one splitting on the hour and two filling in the non worked intervals.

Comment: The return type is still confusing to me - I don't think I'll be able to even *try* to help until I understand the existing code better... (It seems odd that you're adding an hour in `CalculateIntervals` too, given that you're trying to split things into 10 minute intervals...) If you could provide a [mcve] including the expected output from the sample input, that would really help.

Comment: The return type is not important to me and can be anything. I have a block of time between two points of the day and I want to get like  9 am => 0 - 10 Worked, 20 - 40 Not Worked, 50 - 60 Worked for each hour in the day. I will add a possible output class to the end of the questain.

Comment: The return type is important to anyone trying to read and understand the code you've got though. Additionally, you still haven't told us what you want to happen for a period of time which is *partially* worked. If I work from 9:00 to 9:05, but don't work from 9:05 to 9:10, should 9:00 - 9:10 count as worked or not worked? Note also that your "0-10, 20-40 and 50-60" doesn't cover the whole period. What about 10-20 and 40-50? Unless you can be clear in your question, it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: The `DoRounding` method you've now included is rather strange - it uses two 5 minute intervals at the start of the hour, then 10 minute intervals. What are you trying to achieve with that? (It's also *incredibly* inefficient compared with just numeric comparisons, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: I updated above hopes this give more clarity.  I also added a rounding method to handle time outside 10 the minute interval basically rounding it up to the nearest 10 min interval. Each hour is to be broken down to "0-10, 10-20 and 20-30, 30 -40, 40-50, 50-60 " sorry this was a  typo

Comment: How can any time be outside a 10 minute interval? Your rounding method *doesn't* "round it up to the nearest 10 min interval". It behaves pretty oddly IMO, giving one of *7* different answers, when I'd expect 6. I'm afraid at this point everything is *so* confusing I'm leaving this question alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your above explanations I would do the following:

```
public class Interval
{
    public Interval() => Contents = new List<Contents>();

    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public List<Contents> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Contents
{
    public bool Worked { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    //public int End { get; set; }
    public int End => Start + 10;
}

public class WorkPeriod
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Look at the Contents class. The `End` property is autocalculated from the `Start` one.
Then I would create the following `Calculator` class:

```
public class Calculator
{
    public bool[] WorkedIntervals = new bool[24 * 6];

    private void SetWork(int Hour, int Min)
    {
        int pos = Hour * 6 + Min / 10;
        WorkedIntervals[pos] = true;
    }

    private void UpdateIntervals(WorkPeriod period)
    {
        var cur = period.StartTime;
        while (cur < period.EndTime)
        {
            SetWork(cur.Hour, cur.Minute);
            cur = cur.AddMinutes(10);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateIntervals(List<WorkPeriod> periods)
    {
        foreach (var l in periods)
            UpdateIntervals(l);
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<Interval> CalcIntervals(List<WorkPeriod> periods)
    {
        var minTime = (from p in periods
                       select p.StartTime).Min();
        var maxTime = (from p in periods
                       select p.EndTime).Max();

        UpdateIntervals(periods);

        for(int h=minTime.Hour; h<=maxTime.Hour; ++h)
        {
            int pos = h * 6;
            var intrvl = new Interval() { Hour = h };
            for (int m=0; m<=5; m++)
            {
                if (WorkedIntervals[pos + m])
                    intrvl.Contents.Add(new Contents() { Start = m * 10, Worked = true });
                else
                    intrvl.Contents.Add(new Contents() { Start = m * 10, Worked = false });
            }
            yield return intrvl;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that you have to flatten all your time intervals to an array of 144 boolean values (24*6) that represents if each of this 10 minute time interval has been worked or not. eg. if the 7th index of the array is true then it means that at Hour 1 (hour 0 is in indexes 0-5) the 10-20 min interval has been worked.

Then, on your main function you do the following.

```
var input = new List<WorkPeriod>
{
   new WorkPeriod { StartTime  = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 9, 40, 56), EndTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 14, 22, 12) },
   new WorkPeriod { StartTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 9, 50, 56), EndTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 14, 59, 12) },
   new WorkPeriod { StartTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 13, 40, 56), EndTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 18, 22, 12) },
   new WorkPeriod { StartTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 19, 40, 56), EndTime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25, 23, 22, 12) }
};

Calculator ints = new Calculator();
var res = ints.CalcIntervals(input).ToList();
```

The `res` list should contain the hour-intervals from the minimum `StartTime` to the maximum `EndTime` with their respected sub-lists.